# C++ Stack values not working correctly

Tags: c++, stack

I am trying to implement a system that would perform something like say the user enters 4 5 +. It would add the 4 and 5 (9) and push 9 into the stack.
For some reason the values in the stack are huge numbers so I believe it has something to do with a pointer or accessing a wrong field but I'm pulling my hair out trying to find the error. Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include "stack.h"

int main()
{
    stack Test;
    bool stop = false;
    float runningtotal = 0;
    while (stop == false)
    {
        char input;
        cin >> input;
        if (input == '+') {
            int value1 = Test.top();
            Test.pop();
            int value2 = Test.top();
            Test.pop();
            cout << value1+value2 << endl;
            Test.push(value1 + value2);
        }
    cout << Test.top();
    std::getchar();
    std::getchar();
}
```

And the implementation of stack

```
#include "stack.h"
stack::stack()
{
    maxsize = MaxSize;
    currentsize = 0;
    sptr = new StackElement[maxsize];
}

stack::~stack()
{
    delete [] sptr;
}

void stack::push(StackElement data)
{
    if (currentsize < maxsize)
    {
        sptr[currentsize] = data;
        currentsize++;
    } else {
        cout << "Stack is full ;-;";
    }
}

void stack::pop()
{
    if (currentsize == 0) {
        cout << "Empty stack? ;-;";
        return;
    }
    currentsize--;
}

StackElement stack::top()
{
    if (currentsize == 0) {
        cout << "Empty stack u ninja ;-;";
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return (sptr[currentsize]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void stack::push(StackElement data)
{
    if (currentsize < maxsize)
    {
        sptr[currentsize] = data;
        currentsize++; //<--- incrementing after so nothing in [currentsize] now
    } else {
        cout << "Stack is full ;-;";
    }
}


StackElement stack::top()
{
    if (currentsize == 0) {
        cout << "Empty stack u ninja ;-;";
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return (sptr[currentsize]);// should use currentsize-1
                                   // latest filled cell
                                   // since its pushing from top
    }
}
```

Be sure to convert those ascii codes(49 ish) from keyboard to integer type explanations.

```
 input - 48 should do it.
```

Comment: Thank you I would have never spotted that!! That fixes part of it. Now for some reason, if I enter 0 and 0 as the numbers I get a result of 96. And if I go 1 1 + it is 98. So it is partially working. Any idea why such a thing would occur?

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect now :D. But just wondering if that is okay to use? Like it seems like there is a better way than the input - 48?

Comment: Numpad can be erroneous. Can check that too.